# Disabling All Next Form input field if currnt input has an error or warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using a registration form where the user details are checked on keyup event. I would like to disable all the next input field if the current input has an error. I noted that if a user fill incorrect data and start filling the next field. The error is no longer shown. I am using keyup to check the user data. Or you can suggest a way I can keep showing the user that there is an error in specific input fields even if he has started filling another input. This is my jquery code

```
 var spaceReg=/\s/;
 var onlylettersReg=/^[A-Za-z]+$/i;
 var lowUpperCaseReg=/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/;
 var symbolsCheckReg=/[-!$%^&*(){}<>[\]'" . '"|#@:;.,?+=_\/\~]/;
 var noCheckReg=/\d/;
 var timerId=0;
 clearTimeout (timerId);

$("form input[type=text],form input[type=password]").on("keyup",function(event){   
    timerId=setTimeout(function(){
    $('.form_error,.form_warning,.form_warning').fadeOut(3000);
    $('.error_indicator img,.success_indicator img,.warning_indicator img').fadeOut(3000);
    },1000 );
});



 $("#firstname").on("keyup",function(event){

  timerId= setTimeout(function(){
 var dataValid = true;      
 var firstname= $('#firstname').val();
  if( firstname === "" ) //Validation against empty field for fullname
{
              dataValid=false;
$('#firstname_warning').html('<img src="assets/css/warning.png">');
                $("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_warning">Please enter your firstname  in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
                }                 
             else if(onlylettersReg.test(firstname) ===false) //Validation for working email address
{
                dataValid=false;
             $('#firstname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should contain  only letters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#firstname").focus();
}
              else if(firstname.length>15) //Validation for working email address
{
                 dataValid=false;
               $('#firstname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');
$("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should have max of 15 characters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#firstname").focus();
}

              if(dataValid===true){
                      $('#firstname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').fadeIn(3000);
               }else{
                     $('#firstname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').hide();
               }
    },2000);
});

$("#lastname").on(" keyup",function(event){
   var dataValid=true;
 timerId= setTimeout(function(){
 var lastname= $('#lastname').val();

        if( lastname=== "" ) //Validation against empty field for telephone number
{
             dataValid=false;
             $('#lastname_warning').html('<img src="assets/css/warning.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_warning"  >Please enter your last name in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
}
             else if(lastname.length>15) //Validation for working email address
{
              dataValid=false;
              $('#lastname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should have max of 15 characters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
}
             else if(onlylettersReg.test(lastname) ===false) //Validation for working email address
{
              dataValid=false;
               $('#lastname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should contain  only letters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
    }
             if(dataValid===true){
                       $('#lastname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').fadeIn(3000);
               }else{
                     $('#lastname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').hide();
                     $(this).nextAll().hide();
               }
  },2000);     

});
```

This is my form

```
<div id="success_response"></div>
 <div id="failed_response"></div>
<form action="" method="post" id="" autocomplete="off">
<p>
<label for="firstname">First Name:

</label>
<input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstname" autocomplete="off"
      value=""/>


<span id="firstname_warning" class="warning_indicator">  </span>
<span id="firstname_error" class="error_indicator">  </span>
<span id="firstname_success" class="success_indicator">  </span>
<span id="firstname_response"></span>
</p>

<p>
<label for="lastName">Last Name:

</label>
<input name="lastName" type="text"  id="lastname" autocomplete="off"
      value=""/>


<span id="lastname_warning" class="warning_indicator">  </span>
<span id="lastname_error" class="error_indicator">  </span>
<span id="lastname_success" class="success_indicator">  </span>
<span id="lastname_response"></span>
</p>
```

show me how i can ensure that if an error or warnin is continuously show even if the user focus in the next fields and will not be able to sumbit data

Thank you

Comment: Use something like this: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No Problem with Your code Dude...
>     You need Little changes.
>     Change dataValid variable as a global variable and set as true and check in each validation

**Revised Code**

```
var spaceReg=/\s/;


var onlylettersReg=/^[A-Za-z]+$/i;
 var lowUpperCaseReg=/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/;
 var symbolsCheckReg=/[-!$%^&*(){}<>[\]'" . '"|#@:;.,?+=_\/\~]/;
 var noCheckReg=/\d/;
 var timerId=0;
var dataValid = true;      
 clearTimeout (timerId);

$("form input[type=text],form input[type=password]").on("keyup",function(event){   
    timerId=setTimeout(function(){
    $('.form_error,.form_warning,.form_warning').fadeOut(3000);
    $('.error_indicator img,.success_indicator img,.warning_indicator img').fadeOut(3000);
    },1000 );
});



 $("#firstname").on("keyup",function(event){

  timerId= setTimeout(function(){
// var dataValid = true;      
 var firstname= $('#firstname').val();
  if( firstname === "" ) //Validation against empty field for fullname
{
              dataValid=false;
$('#firstname_warning').html('<img src="assets/css/warning.png">');
                $("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_warning">Please enter your firstname  in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
                }                 
             else if(onlylettersReg.test(firstname) ===false) //Validation for working email address
{
                dataValid=false;
             $('#firstname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should contain  only letters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#firstname").focus();
}
              else if(firstname.length>15) //Validation for working email address
{
                 dataValid=false;
               $('#firstname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');
$("#firstname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should have max of 15 characters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#firstname").focus();
}

              if(dataValid===true){
                      $('#firstname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').fadeIn(3000);
               }else{
                     $('#firstname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').hide();
               }
    },2000);
});

$("#lastname").on(" keyup",function(event){
  // var dataValid=true;
 timerId= setTimeout(function(){
 var lastname= $('#lastname').val();
       if(dataValid == true) /* Checking for errors.. Enters if there is NO errors*/
   {
        if( lastname=== "" ) //Validation against empty field for telephone number
  {
             dataValid=false;
             $('#lastname_warning').html('<img src="assets/css/warning.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_warning"  >Please enter your last name in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
}
             else if(lastname.length>15) //Validation for working email address
{
              dataValid=false;
              $('#lastname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should have max of 15 characters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
}
             else if(onlylettersReg.test(lastname) ===false) //Validation for working email address
{
              dataValid=false;
               $('#lastname_error').html('<img src="assets/css/error.png">');

$("#lastname_response").html('<div class="form_error">Sorry, your name should contain  only letters. Thanks.</div>');
$("#lastname").focus();
    }
             if(dataValid===true){
                       $('#lastname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').fadeIn(3000);
               }else{
                     $('#lastname_success').html('<img src="assets/css/success.png">').hide();
                     $(this).nextAll().hide();
               }
  }
  },2000);     

});
```

> U can Use Validate Plugin for simpler validation